# Play ripple effect on view in reverse order

Tags: android, animation, material-design, ripple

The question is pretty much match the title. Does somebody know any simple way to play this new material design ripple animation in reverse order? Like if touch effect comes from borders to center of view. Maybe some thoughts how to subclass `Rippledrawable` to do this?